# Autocovariance Function of this $AR(1)$ Process

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, time-series

Consider the $AR(1)$ process given by $(1-0.6B)(X_{t} - 3) = a_{t}$ where $a_{t} \sim WN(0,1)$ and $B$ is the backshift operator ($X_{t}B = X_{t-1}$).

We can rewrite the process in the more convenient form: $$X_{t} = 0.6 X_{t-1} + 1.2 + a_{t}$$

By way of recursively substitution, we can obtain an $MA(\infty)$ representation, as by $X_{t} = \displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} 0.6^{j} a_{t-j}$, from which it follows that $\gamma(0) = \frac{1}{1-0.6^{2}} = 1.5625$, where $\gamma(k)$ is the autocovariance funtion at lag $k$.

I was interested in determining $\gamma(1)$ and $\gamma(2)$, as well. To do this, I multiplied the above equation by $X_{t-1}$ and $X_{t-2}$ respectively and took the expectation of both sides. This gave the following relations:

$$\gamma(1) = 0.6\gamma(0) + 1.2 \text{ and } \gamma(2)=0.6\gamma(1) + 1.2$$

Everything I've done is pretty straightforward. However, if we multiply the above equation by $X_{t}$ on both sides, taking expectation gives us another expression $\gamma(0) = 0.6\gamma(1) + 1.2 + \sigma^{2}$ which disagrees with the previous determination.

Why do these two determinations of $\gamma(0)$ disagree? What have I done wrong?

Comment: One possible explanation I might have is that my first determination of $\gamma(0)$ ignores the drift of $1.2$. In light of this, I would like to ask if it's just a matter of staying consistent? Another question I would like to ask is if the answer is the same if we work with the original equation or one with the drift removed?

Comment: Are you sure you're taking account of the drift in your $MA(\infty)$ representation? (Are you sure that a $MA(\infty)$ representation exists?)

Comment: What I meant is that I'm not taking the drift into account in the $MA(\infty)$ representation, but I do take it into account for the $\gamma(k)$ expressions. I understand this accounts for the discrepancy, but I'm wondering if the process with drift and with drift removed have the same autocovariance function? So if I just removed the $1.2$ drift, would the answer I get work for the process with drift?

Comment: Multiplying by $X_{t-1}$ on both sides and taking expectations gives $\gamma(1) = 0.6 \gamma(0) + 1.2 E[X_{t-1}]$.

Comment: Right. Given that the expectation of the process $\{X_{t}\}$ is not specified, is it safe to say that we can, without loss of generality, ignore the drift factor of 1.2?

EDIT: Nevermind that, it's clear that the expectation of the process is 3.
If so, would that mean that the autocovariance function for the process with and without drift is the same?

Comment: Given that $E[X_{t-1}]$ isn't specified, you can't just assume it's equal to 1 (or 0). This process might not even be stationary -- check that first before you do anything. If the process isn't stationary, the autocovariance function isn't well-defined.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. In case you didn't see my edit, I determined that the expectation of the process is $3$. Also, the process is in fact stationary since the root of the characteristic equation is outside the unit circle.

Comment: Every $E(X_t)$ is $3$. These nonzero expectations are the reason why you find different results. I would work only on the centered process $(Y_t)$ defined by $Y_t=X_t-3$ since it has the same auto covariance process. Can you redo your computations using $(Y_t)$?

Comment: If you need help doing so, please refer to [this solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/874038/6179) to your other question.